# Hide Grafana table columns from template variable selection

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I have a Table in a Grafana dashboard. It can have multiple columns.
I added a dashboard variable called include_this.
It's a list of what to include in the table, for example: A,B,C,D.

By default I want to have A and B selected, which should show only 4 columns that represent A and B stuff. If the user selected also C, then I would want the table to refresh and add a few more columns that represent C - sort of add more details.

I was hoping that it could be as simple as this in the promql queries I have for each column (this would repeat for each query with its corresponding A, B, C or D):

```
($include_this=~"A") * (sum(my_metric{..}) by (bla))
```

Where I was hoping the first expression would turn true (i.e. user selected A) and allow the metric query to display; otherwise if it turns false (i.e. the user didn't select A), then the column will not have a value and will not be shown. But I keep getting of course errors for the first expression, seems like I can't do code logic like that in the query field?

```
bad_data: invalid parameter "query": 1:4: parse error: unexpected "="
```

Any tips how to approach this?

Comment: Problem of your approach is that `"(A|B|C)"=~"A"` that will be result of substitution of variable into your query is an incorrect expression in promQL. Of the top of my head, I don;t think there is an easy and elegant way of doing this.